# Passing userID into columns of same table and another table

Tags: c#

I am trying to insert record into two tables and fetch the `UserId` of first table and insert into another column of the same table and also into another table but it appears that when I insert data into the tables, the Id of the user is returned and inserted into the second table but inserted a different integer into another column of same first table.

For example, I have `UserTable` and `WalletTable` and I want to insert records simultaneously into the two tables and at the same time fetch the `Id` of `UserTable` and insert into columns of both tables.

Here is the structure of the first table: I want to fetch `UserID` in `UserTable` and insert into `CreatedBy` of `UserTable` and `UserID` of `WalletTable`. But after inserting, I discovered that integer `-1` is inserted into the `CreatedBy` column of `UserTable` and in `WalletTable` the correct `UserID` is inserted.

How can I correct this please?

**UserTable:**

```
UserID | email | pass | con_pass | UserRole | Name | CreatedBy | image | CreateDate
```

**WalletTable:**

```
Id | UserID | email | Name | amount
```

Here is my insert code (C#)

```
if (mailtxtbx.Text != "" & pass.Text != "" & conpass.Text != "" & txtname.Text !="")
{
    if (pass.Text == conpass.Text)
    {
        if (Filedoc.PostedFile.FileName != "")
        {
            if (check1.Checked)
            {
                int Uid = -1;

                byte[] image;
                Stream s = Filedoc.PostedFile.InputStream;
                BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(s);
                image = br.ReadBytes((Int32)s.Length);

                // define query to be executed
                string query = @"INSERT INTO Users (email, pass, con_pass, UserRole, Name, CreatedBy, image, CreateDate) VALUES (@email, @pass, @con_pass, @UserRole, @Name, @CreatedBy, @image, @CreateDate);
                                 SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();";

                // set up SqlCommand in a using block   
                using (SqlCommand objCMD = new SqlCommand(query, con))
                {
                    // add parameters using regular ".Add()" method 
                    objCMD.Parameters.Add("@email", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = mailtxtbx.Text.Trim();
                    objCMD.Parameters.Add("@pass", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = pass.Text.Trim();
                    objCMD.Parameters.Add("@con_pass", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = conpass.Text.Trim();
                    objCMD.Parameters.Add("@UserRole", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = 'A';
                    objCMD.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtname.Text.Trim();
                    objCMD.Parameters.Add("@CreatedBy", SqlDbType.Int, 50).Value = Uid;
                    objCMD.Parameters.Add("@image", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = image;
                    objCMD.Parameters.Add("@CreateDate", SqlDbType.DateTime, 100).Value = DateTime.Now;

                    // open connection, execute query, close connection
                    con.Open();
                    object returnObj = objCMD.ExecuteScalar();

                    if (returnObj != null)
                    {
                        int.TryParse(returnObj.ToString(), out Uid);
                    }
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

                con.Close();

                if (Uid > 0)
                {
                    query = @"INSERT INTO UserWallet (Uid, email, Name, amount) VALUES (@Uid, @email, @Name, @amount)";

                    using (SqlCommand objCMD = new SqlCommand(query, con))
                    {
                        // add parameters using regular ".Add()" method 
                        objCMD.Parameters.Add("@Uid", SqlDbType.Int, 50).Value = Uid;
                        objCMD.Parameters.Add("@email", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = mailtxtbx.Text.Trim();
                        objCMD.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtname.Text.Trim();
                        objCMD.Parameters.Add("@amount", SqlDbType.Float, 100).Value = 0; //Change type here accordingly

                        con.Open();
                        object returnObj = objCMD.ExecuteScalar();

                        if (returnObj != null)
                        {
                            int.TryParse(returnObj.ToString(), out Uid);
                        }
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        lblsuccess.Visible = true;
                        Div1.Visible = true;

                        lblsuccess.Text = "Successfully signed up";
                        lblsuccess.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;

                        lblMessage.Visible = false;
                        dvMessage.Visible = false;
                        mailtxtbx.Text = "";
                        pass.Text = "";
                        conpass.Text = "";
                        txtname.Text = "";
                        // Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
                    }
                }

                con.Close();
             }
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: "fetch the UserId of first table and insert into another column of the same table" Why do you want the same data in 2 columns of the same table? I'm finding your requirements paragraph hard to follow.

Comment: Why do you keep calling `ExecuteScalar` on your `objCMD` and the `ExecuteNonQuery` on the `cmd` query?? What does this accomplish? You haven't shown us what the `cmd` is and does .....

Comment: I want the same data in 2 columns of the same table because there is a logic came up with in my project..which will be used to identify and link two users on the platform

Comment: Marc, calling ExecuteNonQuery is a mistake; it appears once in my code. It's a typo error. But still,  it's giving me the same result